# Can I use a javascript bookmarklet to copy a Youtube transcript without timestamps, now that they removed this option?

Tags: javascript, youtube, bookmarklet, caption

There used to be an option on Youtube to remove timestamps from the transcript, which I often used to copy it to the clipboard. No longer. Now my solution is to go into the Code Inspector, and set the class property to `display:none`. It works, but I'd like to automate it with a bookmarklet. This is as far as I've gone:

```
function() {
    var trans = '';
    const captions = document.querySelectorAll("ytd-transcript-segment-renderer > div > yt-formatted-string");
    for (let i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
        trans += ' ' + captions[i].textContent
    };
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(trans)
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it!

```
javascript: (function() {
    var captions = "";
    document.querySelector("ytd-menu-service-item-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(2) > tp-yt-paper-item:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)").click();
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("ytd-transcript-segment-renderer > div > yt-formatted-string")).forEach(caption => captions += caption.textContent + " ");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(captions)
})()
```

Can it be improved?

Comment: It can! I'm just missing something for the code to wait the browser load the transcript. Can I fix that with `async` / `await`?

Answer (score -1):

```
function filtered(trans) {
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { // number
    valeur = trans.replace(i, '');
  }
  valeur = trans.replace(',', '');
  valeur = trans.replace('=', '');
  valeur = trans.replace(':', '');
  valeur = trans.replace('-->', '');

  return valeur;
}

filtered(trans);
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.